# How can it be that $\bar{A}=\{\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n:B_\varepsilon(\vec{x})\cap A\ne \emptyset\text{ for all } \varepsilon>0\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

One question asks to verify that $\bar{A}=\{\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n:B_\varepsilon(\vec{x})\cap A\ne \emptyset\text{ for all } \varepsilon>0\}$. But how can this definition be true if we can replace $\bar{A}$ with $A$ and this definition would still apply? I think I'm not understanding something, so I would appreciate some clarification.

Comment: Well, it's not true that you can replace $\overline{A}$ with $A$; for example, if $A = (0, 1)$ then $1 \in \{x : B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap A \ne \emptyset \text{ for all } \epsilon > 0\}$ but $1 \notin A$.

Comment: Never ever say 'this definition be true' by the way.

Comment: Right, an open ball centered at an endpoint will intersect with $A$, but the endpoint is not in an open set. I was just not viewing this under the correct angle conceptually (was imagining a different concept in fact). Bad attention.